# SharpZipLib throw System.IO.FileNotFoundException on commit update

Tags: c#, .net, zip

When I run `AddAndUpdate()` within a loop I get this error but **not** always so it is also working sometimes and it is with the **SAME** data.

I tried to put `Task.Delay` but that is not working either. I thought it could be sometimes with disk writing. Anyone know what it  can be?

The `ZipFile` get closed when the `CompressionProvider` is disposed, but that does not happen in the loop.

```
protected void CreateIfNull()
{
    if (_zipFile != null) return;
    _zipFile = ZipFile.Create(_filePath);
}


private async Task AddAndUpdateAsync(string containerName, string blobName, string prefix)
{
    if (!await _storage.BlobExistsAsync(containerName, blobName))
    {
        return;
    }

    using (var stream = await _storage.GetBlobStreamAsync(containerName, blobName))
    {
    string fileName = Path.Combine(prefix, containerName, blobName);
        AddAndUpdate(stream, fileName);
    }
}

public void AddAndUpdate(string containerName, string blobName, string prefix = "")
{
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lockObject);
        Microsoft.Threading.AsyncPump.Run(async delegate
        {
            await AddAndUpdateAsync(containerName, blobName, prefix);
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
    }
}

public void AddAndUpdate(Stream stream, string filePath)
{
    if (stream == null || stream.Length == 0) return;

    CreateIfNull();
    _zipFile.BeginUpdate();
    _zipFile.Add(new CustomStaticDataSource(stream), ZipEntry.CleanName(filePath));
    _zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

Here is the trace:

> ```
> Test Name:    TestExport
> Test FullName:    Company.App.UnitTest.ExportTest.TestExport
> Test Source:  C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.AppUnitTest\ExportTest.cs : line 45
> Test Outcome: Failed
> Test Duration:    0:00:08,2825027
>
> Result StackTrace:    
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>    at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.DiskArchiveStorage.ConvertTemporaryToFinal()
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.RunUpdates()
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.CommitUpdate()
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.AddAndUpdate(Stream stream, String filePath) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 77
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.<AddAndUpdateAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 45
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<AddAndUpdate>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 56
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>    at Microsoft.Threading.AsyncPump.Run(Func`1 func) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Utilities\AsyncPump.cs:line 32
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.AddAndUpdate(String containerName, String blobName, String prefix) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 62
>    at Company.App.UnitTest.ExportTest.<TestExport>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.AppUnitTest\ExportTest.cs:line 65
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
> Result Message:   
> Test method Company.App.UnitTest.ExportTest.TestExport threw exception: 
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.AppUnitTest\TestData\export.zip.361.tmp'.
> Result StandardOutput:    
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.AppUnitTest\TestData\export.zip.361.tmp'.
> File name: 'C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.AppUnitTest\TestData\export.zip.361.tmp'
>    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>    at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.DiskArchiveStorage.ConvertTemporaryToFinal()
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.RunUpdates()
>    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.CommitUpdate()
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.AddAndUpdate(Stream stream, String filePath) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 77
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.<AddAndUpdateAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 45
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<AddAndUpdate>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 56
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>    at Microsoft.Threading.AsyncPump.Run(Func`1 func) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Utilities\AsyncPump.cs:line 32
>    at Company.Compression.CompressionProvider.AddAndUpdate(String containerName, String blobName, String prefix) in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Templex\Company.Compression\CompressionProvider.cs:line 54
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like GetBlobStreamAsync and BlobExistsAsync was not thread safe when the storage provider was LocalStorage.